# Interface Builder: automatically set aspect ratio for UIImageView when using "Aspect Fit"?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, autolayout, storyboard, interface-builder

The share icon (image is white) below is 114x128 pixels.

Fixing the height in Interface Builder to 23 pixels with AutoLayout then using **Aspect Fit** for the **Content Mode** does not change the frame rectangle, though.

This causes issues with alignment since if you want the icon 15 pixels from the trailing edge, it's now hard to do so.

One option is to manually set the aspect ratio (i.e., 114/128) as an AutoLayout constraint within IB.

But this is extremely fragile. If you change the image dimensions, you must remember to adjust the aspect ratio.

Is there a way where IB automatically adjusts the frame rectangle as well as the content?

The last option is to do everything within code, but doing everything within IB would be ideal.

**Frame rectangle not changing in IB:**

[image]

**Share icon (white icon so not visible here):**

[image]

Comment: .contentMode doesn't change frame. Only the way the image is displayed within the frame.

I think the only way to achieve what you want is with code.

Comment: @Demosthese if you are right, this is frustrating. it makes so much more sense that the frame changes with the content, or else you run into the alignment issues described above. argh, apple!

Comment: Well, it's super easy to do in code. Like a single line. Why not?

Comment: @Demosthese because there are many more icons :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'll have to do this programmatically. If you don't want to do it view by view, just define some subclass (which you can specify as the base class in IB) that sets constraints programmatically

```
class RatioImageView: UIImageView {

    private var ratioConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

    override var image: UIImage? {
        didSet { updateRatioConstraint() }
    }

    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        super.didMoveToSuperview()

        updateRatioConstraint()
    }

    private func updateRatioConstraint() {
        if let ratioConstraint = ratioConstraint {
            removeConstraint(ratioConstraint)
        }

        guard superview != nil else { return }

        let ratio: CGFloat
        if let image = image {
            ratio = image.size.width / image.size.height
        } else {
            ratio = 1
        }

        ratioConstraint = widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor, multiplier: ratio)
        ratioConstraint?.isActive = true
    }
}
```

This does it on an image view, but you could presumably do the same with `UIButton` or whatever, too.

---

Or in another variation of the theme, you could control this with intrinsic size, where perhaps you explicitly set the `height` (and because this is `@IBInspectable`, you can do this right in IB), and it will return the intrinsic size scaled for that height:

```
@IBDesignable
class RatioImageView: UIImageView {

    @IBInspectable var height: CGFloat = 0

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        guard let image = image else { return .zero }
        guard height > 0 else { return image.size }

        let ratio = image.size.width / image.size.height

        return CGSize(width: height * ratio, height: height)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! So frustrating this isn't done automatically by IB. Why adjust the content but not the frame??? Perhaps there is some reason, but it's not clear at all.