# How to correctly remove a VC from memory - swift

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, uiviewcontroller, uianimation

I have an application with a Home Screen and a number of VC's to be presented. I have created an Animation class, which takes care of my transitions, but on inspecting the memory, the usage is continually increasing.

**This is my animation**

```
static func showScreen(_ vc: UIViewController, _ start: CGPoint, _ next: UIViewController) {
    // Global variable to determine whether animations are enabled
    if animate {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            next.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.01, y: 0.01)
            next.view.center = start
            vc.view.superview?.insertSubview(next.view, aboveSubview: vc.view)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, animations: {
                next.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.15, y: 0.15)
                next.view.center = CGPoint(x: screenSize.width/2, y: screenSize.height/2)
            }) { finished in
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                    next.view.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
                }) { finished in
                    vc.present(next, animated: false)
                    BlockApp().unblock()
                }
            }
        }
    } else { vc.present(next, animated: false)  }
}
```

**Edit: Second Animation**

```
static func goHome(_ vc: UIViewController, _ b: Bool, _ delay: Double = 0) {
  //  let next = vc.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainMenu") as! mainMenu
//  After replacing the above line of code with the following, the deinit{} method gets called on the ViewController, but only when returning to it and still not removing it from memory
    let next = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainMenu") as! mainMenu
    if animate {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            vc.view.superview?.insertSubview(next.view, belowSubview: vc.view)

            var target = CGPoint(x: vc.view.frame.width/2, y: 0)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: delay, animations: {
                vc.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)
            }) { finished in
                if b {
                    if next.collectionView != nil {
                        if let position = next.collectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at: selectedPosition) {
                            let dest = position.center
                            target = CGPoint(x: dest.x, y: dest.y + next.titleView.frame.height + 80)
                        }
                    }
                }
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                    vc.view.center = target
                }) { finished in
                    vc.present(next, animated: false)
                    BlockApp().unblock()
                }
            }
        }
    } else { vc.present(next, animated: false)  }
}
```

The method takes as arguments the activeVC, the starting position of the animation and the VC to be presented. I understand GC happens when needed, but by spamming screens I can reach 1 GB of memory in use (didn't try more as it took a bit of time and the device has about 3).

**Questions**

1. How do I remove all VC's from memory and keep only the one that gets
           presented?
2. On the VC I am presenting, viewWillAppear gets called twice (once
   for the transform, second once presented). Is there a way to only
       have it called once whilst keeping the preview of the page while animating?

**Tried**

1. `vc.dismiss` after presenting next
2. using `vc.navigationController.viewControllers` to remove all other controllers, but the array is always nil
3. adding `self.presentingViewController?.removeFromParentViewController()` to the presented VC

Comment: Are you calling `dismiss` on any of these VC's where you're calling `present`? This is a "modal" presentation, meaning it's supposed to show up (typically, a "slide-up" transition) and there should be a "done" button to get out of it.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question. Yes, but the dismiss seems to reset all constraints and present a distorted vc of the original

Comment: Are you sure the problem is that view controllers are not being properly deallocated or is that just an assumption based on the app's memory usage?

Comment: @iabuseservers suppose it’s mostly assumption based on checking the variables and data stored. There is no way the globals affected add MBs in memory usage (plus specifically removing values from memory on viewDidDissapear() as an attempt to fix ). Once a view gets instantiated, memory usage increases by an amount, then seconds later, when processing is completed it decreases by about 10% of that and never goes down again. So if I open and close a vc 10 times, I’ll end up with about 9* the memory increase .

Comment: There are two easy ways to make sure objects are being deallocated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999334/how-to-list-all-live-non-deallocated-uiviewcontrollers/47999548#47999548 let's make sure we're attempting to solve the right problem, first

Comment: Thanks @iabuseservers, that hit the nail on the head, multiple instances of the vc’s are stored in the memory, so they’re never released. Any idea how to remove them or what could be causing these issues?

Comment: Either you have accidentally created a `strong` reference to those instances, such as in the view controller that instantiated them, or you did not properly deallocate them in your custom navigation or presentation controller objects. Before you go any deeper, make those instances weak by writing `weak var someViewController = SomeViewController()` and see if that does anything. If not, let's go deeper.

Comment: Please see my question, I have edited with the other animation used. I have tried declaring the next VC inside as a weak var but it ended up with a lot of nil errors. However, you are right, the vc's left in memory are meant to be removed from this second animation. So whilst first animation doesn't leave initialised views, this second one does. Only difference is the location where the VC variable is created (1st is created inside the active VC and passed as argument, 2nd creates it inside the animation class)